# Computer graphics - how to map Point (Real, Real) to Point (Integer, Integer) of screen

Tags: graphics

I am planning to draw a set of Points into Canvas and all these Points will look like :

A(1.32324234, 2.5353427), B(12.2523256, 20.05232398532)...

I know that to draw a Point in computer screen, if the screen resolution is 1920x1080, we will have a set of Point in this space between (0,0) to (1919, 1079), so what algorithm in Computer Graphics can do map those Points in REAL numbers to those Points in Integer numbers precisely?

The range of original Points will be in (0,0) to (297.0, 210.0), actually it's in an A4 size paper.

Comment: What range do the original points have?

Comment: Point (X, Y), the X belong to (0.0, 297.0), the Y belong to (0.0, 210.0)

Comment: Hah, landscape A4 measurements in millimeters. Divide your x,y through these values and you get a 0..1 mapping. Multiply by your screen size (or possibly, your *window* size) and you have your screen coordinates.

Comment: Sounds cool, let me try

Comment: Thanks, @Jongware, I tried, and it's good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know the viewpoint in real space and a transform to screen coordinates.  It's view and screen resolution dependent, of course.

Something like this will get you started:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix

And this:

http://www.cs.trinity.edu/~jhowland/cs3353/3d-viewing/3d-viewing/